# 500 Error in this code mongodb and node js all connection good when i add objectid then gives 500 and without this 400

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

```
<body>
    <script>
        app.get('/api/data/projects/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);

  async function getDataFromCollection() {
    try {
      const database = client.db('projects'); // Replace with your database name
      const collection = database.collection('project_info'); // Replace with your collection name
    
      const data = await collection.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) });
      console.log('Retrieved data:', data);
    
      if (data) {
        res.json(data);
      } else {
        res.status(404).json({ error: 'Data not found' });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving data from the collection', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
    
  }
  
  getDataFromCollection();
});
    </script>
</body>
```

I want exepcting to access my data by api in json format. my connection is working. every thing is fine i get my post id but data not geting 500 error.

Comment: const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/data/projects/${id}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setItem(data);
        console.log(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

Comment: Check i am confuse where i did wrong. id is pass to my api its show me my id mongo db connection is worrking data base and collection is i have by same name i have 10 entry in my collection every one have id same in post is but geting error 500

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of this.

500, 400 error in this code was:

> Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new'

So, the answer is adding *new* in before `ObjectId`:

```
const data = await collection.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) });
```